# Inject a Stateless Session Bean into an Exception Interceptor?

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, interceptor

I have an Exception Interceptor that works like this:

```
public class ExceptionInterceptor
{
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object exceptionHandler(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception
    {
        try {
            return ctx.proceed();
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            // Log Exception Here

            throw re;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to inject a LogManagerBean so I can do something like this:

```
public class ExceptionInterceptor
{
    @EJB
    LogManagerBean logManager;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object exceptionHandler(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception
    {
        try {
            return ctx.proceed();
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            // Log Exception Here
            logManager.error(re);

            throw re;
        }
    }
}
```

The LogManagerBean is marked `@Stateless` and `@LocalBean`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's possible. As in the case of other interceptors. Interceptors is created at the same time as the EJB instance is created, and dependency is injected before calling the first method of EJB.

Comment: Wow. I don't know what I did wrong in the first place, but I went and tried it again and it worked just fine. Weird. Thanks.